# SSAS: Linking multiple fact tables

Tags: many-to-many, ssas

Question: Best practice for linking two fact tables together? Referenced, many-to-many or just "normal" multidimensional modeling. It is a one to many relationship. (One Journey to many Products, see below).

Background: Have a really great job for a travel agency. They sell full "packages", say you would like to go to Africa for 4 weeks and have a lot have different tours (safaris, etc), different hotels, multiple flights, insurance, and so on. It would be pretty hard if you were to put together that travel by yourself - so thats what "my" company can help put together.

One "Journey" contains multiple "Products". A journey have multiple dates attached, different status codes, owners etc etc. What i am wondering is how best to connect the journey level to the product level (tours, insurance, etc), so that when you choose a Journey Creation Date you can see all the products lines that are attached.

- I could make a bridge table and many-to-many relations?
- I could put the "Journey Creation Date" / "Journey Status" as "normal" FK on my Product Fact Table?
- Or perhaps referenced?

Are there any rules of thumb i should consider here? Its a large cube concerning the number of dimensions and fact tables, but not so big if you consider the amount of data.

There are 7 dimensions on the Journey level that should be avaiable for the Product level.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bridge table and many-to-many relations.